# Using an unsupported API in Android Wear

Tags: android-webview, wear-os

I'm really keen to develop a web browser application for Android Wear devices. To make such application I need a **WebView** object, but the major problem is that Google has made the **android.webkit** API unavailable in that OS.


Since Android is open-source, is it technically possible to manually include the needed libraries, by coping them from the android source code on GitHub into my project? Are they going to work like as in a normal Android device, and is it legal?

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/core/java/android/webkit) is the link to the API I'd like to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing a browser based on WebView is not a good idea anyway. Although historically Android Browser was based on WebView, it had to use a lot of hidden APIs in order to work. All more or less functional browser apps based on WebView have to do the same, which makes them fragile. Also, the resulting browser app will not be as secure as a real multi-process web browser.

A better idea is to take [Chromium](http://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions) and build it using Wear SDK. And there is already [one built this way](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appfour.wearbrowser&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to a complete source for Android Wear to build a complete image.